# SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" error when using log4j

Tags: java, maven, log4j, slf4j

I am using log4j dependency in my maven project. But I get following warning related slf4j. But I only have log4j dependency in my pom.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I looked at the http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder adnd tried adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.29</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

to the code. But it did not work. Any clarifications?

Comment: You probably want groupId `org.apache.logging.log4j`, this one is from 2012

Comment: @boot-and-bonnet It says there is no dependency like that when I change the groupId

Comment: this should be the latest - https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j (2.12.1)

Comment: **Option 1:** To get rid of the error, just change the `slf4j-log4j12` dependency scope to compile. **Option 2:** If you want to use log4j only, then make sure your other dependencies are not pulling slf4j-api jar (i.e. transitive dependency).

Comment: @Ramu If dependencies transitively require SLF4J then you can't just not pull it in; that would cause at least one `NoClassDefFoundError` to be thrown during execution.

Comment: @wmlbb In addition to using the correct groupId (i.e. `org.apache.logging.log4j`) and latest version (i.e. `2.12.1`), if you have any dependencies which transitively require SLF4J then you need to add the `log4j-slf4j-impl` binding to your dependencies. That will allow SLF4J to use Log4J as the implementation.

Comment: @Slaw Sorry, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

As you said [SLf4J](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder) site given a solution that resolves this issue. Follow that and add `slf4j-simple-1.7.29.jar` to your application along with `slf4j-api-1.7.29.jar`.

**SLF4J Simple Binding » 1.7.29**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.29</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**SLF4J API Module » 1.7.29**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.29</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this helps you and others who have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>

        </dependency>

                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

You log4j.properties will be 

# Root logger option
#log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file
log4j.logger.com.dnd.ncprdatacouch=DEBUG, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


you should use following

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NcprCouchFullDump.class);

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
#log4j.appender.file.File=C:/vivek/go/logs/log4j-application.log
log4j.appender.file.File=<your Path>/log4j-application.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=30MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=50
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```